# Aquaris E5 HD Ubuntu Edition - Ubuntu Updates

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq

what about the updates for Aquaris E5 HD Ubuntu Edition?
How long and when will i get the newest ubuntu phone versions for this product?
I don't want to have a second Android update disaster.
Regards, Arthur

Comment: So are you asking 'will ubuntu on the Aquaris E5 be updated'?

Comment: Yes, and how long will be updates available? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your english is fine :D its a good question, I just don't think many people know the answer... it might follow the standard ubuntu release dates as shown [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) (e.g. 13.10 is End of Life), but I think you can easily update to the next release - some more stuff (mainly for devlopers) on this [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)

Comment: Okay, but an over the air update would be nice. I don't want to build my own  distro :-) And of course you know the update desaster with android (for example samsung...). I am sure there has to be any ubuntu update specially for Aquaris E5 HD hardware at every distribution, or not?

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your help. No firmware updates needed, only an ubuntu upgrade?

Comment: How can i mark this question as answered?

Comment: Firmware updates may be included with the software updates - most of the time you probably don't need them anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This bit](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/#upgrade-ubuntu) of the devloper documentation says that it can automatically - this should mean that unlike on many android devices, you can apply updates to the system, and have the latest release (if there is a image available.....):

> ## Upgrading Ubuntu
>
> ### Upgrading automatically
>
> After installing Ubuntu, upgrades to newly released images and apps
> are automatically provided through **Settings > Updates. Tip:** You
> can configure such updates to never install automatically in
> **Settings > Updates.**

There is also documentation on how manually to flash images onto the device (meaning you could install the next release image even if it is not yet stable). You have to be careful here in case it 'bricks' it (stops it working - it become a useless brick :)